# JPA, Hibernate and Oracle function Index

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I got an entity like this

```
@Table(indexes = { @Index(columnList = "UPPER(name)", name="index_name") })
@Entity public class Thing {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
}
```

and i want an oracle functional index on this because the name is mostly queried as uppercase value (but case matters when retrieving the data) I want an oracle functional index. Is it possible to do this with hibernate or jpa?

Currently i get the following error: `database column 'UPPER(name)' not found` (well i awaited an error with the use of just UPPER(name) but was worth the try)

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just do this (below)? Hibernate will map the index name automatically to upper case if it it Oracle.

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Thing {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Index(name = "index_name")
   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;
```

}

Oracle will have a column with name 'NAME' and an index on it with name 'INDEX_NAME'.

Comment: It's not about the name, but the indexed content. OP wants to index the result of `UPPER(name)` and not just the value `name`.